# Cant download qt-components-ubuntu on my machine

Tags: application-development, ubuntu-touch

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I install the QML toolkit on 12.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/235440/how-do-i-install-the-qml-toolkit-on-12-04)

I was trying to get some hands on ubuntu mobile app development and followed the instructions of downloading the qt5-beta. But I was not able to get following components to get installed on my ubuntu 12.04 machine. Am i missing anything on my apt-get? Seems the package hosting server is not available for the below packages.

On apt-get update :

Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/ui-toolkit/ppa/ubuntu/dists/precise/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found

On trying to install from different packages

E: Unable to locate package qt-components-ubuntu
E: Unable to locate package qt-components-ubuntu-demos
E: Unable to locate package qt-components-ubuntu-examples
E: Unable to locate package qt-components-ubuntu-doc
E: Unable to locate package notepad-qml

Appreciate your help in resolving this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

That's because these packages are compiled for quantal (12.10), not for precise (12.04).